# How do I enlarge /home and /swap partitions on GNU/Linux?

Tags: partition, storage, ram

Well, I've gotten myself into a sticky situation. I've just upgraded my laptop's RAM from 8 GB to 16 GB. Now, I know that Linux `swap` partition serves as a "home" for RAM on most Linux distros, including mine. Also, I have my Linux on a 1 TB HDD. However, when first installing, I've only used 700 GB out of 1 TB and naively thought that I could enlarge later if it were needed. So, 300 GB is basically just laying around doing nothing.

Well, now I need a bigger `home` and `swap` partition. However, even after running `gparted`, I only had the option to **shrink** these partitions, despite of 300 GB of space marked as 'Unallocated'. Please help me figure out how to enlarge both, so my RAM and storage capacity won't go to waste. Thank you in advance.

Addendum: the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
root@smerdjakov:~# sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK1059GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1048kB  610GB   610GB   extended                  boot
 5      1049kB  2000MB  1999MB  logical   ext4
 6      2001MB  102GB   100GB   logical   ext4
 7      102GB   602GB   500GB   logical   ext4
 8      602GB   610GB   7999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "swap partition serves as a home" for RAM? That doesn't make much sense. There's no reason to increase your swap just because you got more RAM, unless you often use all of your RAM and then hibernate your machine. Anyway, please [edit] your question and show us the output of `sudo parted -l`. Also, why don't you just create a new partition in the empty space and mount that in a directory under your home? Why do you need to enlarge?

Comment: I don't know, it just seems more convenient to keep my setup as it is. I'll edit my question in no time. "Swap serves as home to RAM" means that the `swap` acts as RAM storage for my system (sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not very keen on this technical terminology; hence the misunderstanding).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: When you increase RAM, you need less swap, not the opposite. That's just cargo cult from the past (and from a few old versions of Linux where it was required to have at least as much). What you should do is remove the swap entirely because it's in the way of the free 300GB and it's easy to do (but see Why is Kali so hard...). Had you used LVM, you'd have more options

Comment: @HaukeLaging come on. Please stop using that post as a dupe for anything mentioning Kali. The basic problem here is about MBR extended partitions and has absolutely nothing to do with the OS being used.

Comment: Do you get the same restriction from `(g)parted` if you boot from a Rescue CD?

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the suggestion! By the way, what is 'LVM'? A 'Live Mode', I presume?

Comment: @roaima Hold on just a sec, imma check up on it.

Comment: LVM = http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux) ... usually done at installation or too late to be useful

Comment: @roaima Yep, Rescue CD returns the same output.

Comment: @A.B I've just deleted my `swap` partition and edited `/etc/fstab` so that my system doesn't think that something's missing when booting up. But I still get the message: "Gave up waiting for suspend/remove device". How do I get rid of it? I've also only been able to enlarge my `home` partition by the size of my old `swap` partition. Neither `GParted` nor Windows Disk Manager (I have two HDDs in my laptop, one for each OS) can do anything about it. Help???

Comment: For the suspend/remove(?) thing, you'll have to search all settings (ie all /etc) for a reference to the swap partition used for hibernation etc. For the size, that's because the logical partition envelope (primary partition 1) is not spanning the whole disk but only 610MB. That's why I never use logical partitions... . I won't suggest how to enlarge it, because I don't want to be responsible for data loss

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need that much swap. Unless hibernating when all RAM is in use, you will need less swap.

You can not resize through a partition that is in use. So you need to disable the swap use `swapoff` to disable it. Then you can move the swap (if still needed). Then resize it (if needed), then resize the other partitions.

Alternatively add additional partition(s), and mount them somewhere. This would be less flexible. As you have to manage what is on each partition.

Alternatively consider LVM, I have no idea if this can be done retrospectively. Hopefully some one else can give an answer to that.

---

From comment: you seem to have remove the swap. but not told the OS not to use it. Look in fstab, and remove the line related to swap, to disable swap.

Comment: I've already fixed the "Gave up..." error, but it required more than just editing the `fstab` file (I had to recompile some `.config` files for some reason). I'm considering making a Kali GNU/Linux bootable USB drive. Through the process of installation, there is also a disk/partition manager. Maybe **this particular one** will have no problem resizing my `home` partition. Also, what is the difference between `logical` and `primary` partitions?

Comment: Logical/physical are a sort of kludge of the way partitions are/were done on PC. The partition table has only 4 entries, so someone came up with an extension, where you add and extended partition, this has another partition table, and a set of (logical) partitions. Thus allowing more than 4.